# Comparing two columns in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013

If I have two columns

```
2 11
9 4
7 8
```

How can I get the number of times that column #1 value was bigger than column #2 (once in this case)?

Comment: How far did you get?

Comment: Not quite sure how to do this ? If you mean, how many rows per column, I have 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comparing on a row by row basis, you could use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A1000>B1:B1000))
```